# How to look for up all/search for the methods in pycharm with a given name

Tags: pycharm

In Eclipse, if we want to see all the available methods in a given class, we can use the short cut Ctrl + O and it will show all the methods in the current class. Also, it will filter the methods that start with a given name, as we type in the name of the method.

What is the equivalent short for this in Pycharm?

Thanks!

Comment: What platform? Which bindings? Why don't you just look this up in the documentation?

Comment: I am trying this on Windows operating system.  @jonrsharpe what do you mean by bindings?I tried to look up in the documentation and in the forums, but i could not find any. May be i am not looking in the right place.

Comment: On Mac OS X you get a choice of key bindings, the same may be true of other platforms. You can always use Ctrl-Shift-A to search for actions, which will tell you the shortcut too. See https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm will suggest methods and attributes while typing. So if you for instance type `str().`, PyCharm will display a list with suggested items to follow, which will narrow down as soon as you continue typing. You can enforce the *Code Completion* by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> inside a function or method, you can display its parameters, too.

You can configure everything to your needs in *Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion*. You can find more useful shortcuts in the [PyCharm help](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/keyboard-shortcuts-you-cannot-miss.html).